# Book I read 26 years ago where the protagonist visits a therapist and talks about dreams and trains

Tags: story-identification, books

I have very little recollection of the book other than the general theme (augmented humans fight across space and possibly time). On particular thread in the book was the protagonist's recurring visits to a therapist (psychiatrist). During these visits, he speaks about dreams and trains running through tunnels. He later realizes that this recurring dream is one of the few memories of his mother (taking his temperature with a rectal thermometer...)

Comment: The bit about thermometers is in Pohl's Gateway, butvthecother parts don't fit